# In Exchange Online Protection, one contact became a mailbox. How did this happen?

Tags: exchangeonline

Today I noticed that I had not received any external mail. I tried mailing myself, but it did not get through to our on-premises mail server. I checked EOP, and there I was in the mail box list. I had disappeared from the contact list. I tried renaming the mailbox, but that did not work. After removing the mailbox, I could add a contact. Mail flow was successfully restored. I have two questions:

How did this happen? I have been trying to use my work account for Teams instead of my personal account. Could something I did there caused this.

Is it possible to recover the contents of the removed mailbox? (This was less important than restoring mail flow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Could you receive NDRs? What are specific error messages in these NDRs?

Run the admin audit log to check if there were some admins modify something which was related with this issue.

2. Yes, you could recover the content of the removed mailbox, first, restore this mailbox and export contents and import content to the new one. For more details: [Restore a user mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/delete-or-restore-mailboxes#restore-a-user-mailbox)

Comment: No NDR's. I assume my messages were delivered to the now deleted mailbox. Thank you for your excellent reply.